# enzyme react testing .contains() not matching

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

Hi there I am using Enzyme to test my react components. I was wondering what's the best way to test the fact that the component I am testing DOES include a certain child component with a certain props?

So far I have no success in doing this:

InlineEdit.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

export default class InlineEdit extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
      label: PropTypes.string,
      value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };    
    static defaultProps = {
      label: null,
    };

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        isOn: false,
        inputValue: props.value,
      }
      this.showInput = this.showInput.bind(this)
      this.hideInput = this.hideInput.bind(this)
      this.handleDisplayTextChange = this.handleDisplayTextChange.bind(this)
      this.debouncedHandleKeyDown = debounce(this.debouncedHandleKeyDown.bind(this), 200)
      this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
      this.checkIfChanged = this.checkIfChanged.bind(this)
      this.commitChange = this.commitChange.bind(this)
      this.discardChange = this.discardChange.bind(this)
    }

    showInput() {
      this.setState({
        isOn: true,
      }, 
      () => {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.namedInput).select()
      })
    }

    hideInput() {
      this.setState({
        isOn: false,
      })
    }

    handleDisplayTextChange(e) {
      this.setState({inputValue:e.target.value})
    }

    debouncedHandleKeyDown(key) {
      if( key == 'Enter') {
        this.commitChange()
      } else if ( key == 'Escape') {
        this.discardChange()
      }
    }

    handleKeyDown(e) {
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123055/react-keyboard-event-handlers-all-null
      this.debouncedHandleKeyDown(e.key)
    }

    checkIfChanged() {
      return this.state.inputValue !== this.props.value
    }

    commitChange() {
      this.hideInput()
      if(this.checkIfChanged()){
        this.props.onChange(this.state.inputValue)  
      }
    }
    discardChange(){
      this.hideInput()
      this.setState({inputValue: this.props.value})
    }

    render() {
      const { 
        onChange,
        value,
        label,
      } = this.props;

      const {
        isOn,
        inputValue,
      } = this.state;

      return  <span style={{
                borderBottom: '1px dashed #000',
              }}>
                { 
                  !isOn 
                    ? <span onDoubleClick={this.showInput}>{label || value}</span>
                    : <input 
                        ref="namedInput"
                        onChange={this.handleDisplayTextChange}
                        onBlur={this.commitChange}
                        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                        value={inputValue}
                      />
                }
              </span>
    }
}
```

LineItemRow.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import InlineEdit from './InlineEdit';

const LineItemRow = ({
  project,
}) => (
  <div>
    <InlineEdit 
      value={project.name} />
  </div>
)
LineItemRow.propTypes = {
  project: PropTypes.object,
};

export default LineItemRow;
```

LineItemRow.spec.js

```
import React from 'react';
import shallow from 'enzyme/shallow';
import expect from 'expect';
import sinon from 'sinon';

import { LineItemRow } from './LineItemRow';
import InlineEdit from '../lib/components/InlineEdit';
import LineItemSelectBox from './LineItemSelectBox';

describe('<LineItemRow /> component', function () {
  const setup = () => {
    const props = {
      project: {id: 1, name: '1000'},
    }
    const output = shallow(<LineItemRow {...props} />)
    return {
      output,
      props,
    }
  }

  it.only('should contain project name', function () {
    const { output, props } = setup()
    const actual  = output.contains(<InlineEdit value={props.project.name} />) // THIS IS FALSE
    const expected= true

    expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
  });

});
```

//package.json

```
    {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha './app/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-register --recursive --require testSetup.js",
        "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=dev node server.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
        "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
        "babel-plugin-react-hot": "^1.0.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "enzyme": "^2.2.0",
        "eslint": "^2.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
        "expect": "^1.16.0",
        "happypack": "^2.1.1",
        "jsdom": "^8.2.0",
        "mocha": "^2.4.5",
        "mocha-jsdom": "^1.1.0",
        "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
        "npm-check-updates": "^2.8.9",
        "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "react-addons-perf": "^15.1.0",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0",
        "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
        "react-render-visualizer": "^0.2.2",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
        "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
        "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.11",
        "sinon": "^1.17.3",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "webpack": "^1.13.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.3.0",
        "why-did-you-update": "0.0.8"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "Faker": "^0.7.2",
        "aphrodite": "^1.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.12.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "color": "^0.11.3",
        "counterpart": "^0.17.4",
        "cuid": "^1.3.8",
        "damals": "^0.9.4",
        "delay": "^1.3.1",
        "draft-js": "^0.7.0",
        "draft-js-export-html": "^0.3.0",
        "fecha": "^2.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
        "halogen": "^0.2.0",
        "history": "^2.0.1",
        "humanize-plus": "^1.8.2",
        "intl": "^1.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.13.1",
        "memoizee": "^0.3.10",
        "normalizr": "^2.1.0",
        "pluralize": "^3.0.0",
        "query-string": "^4.2.2",
        "query-string-parser": "^0.1.4",
        "react": "^15.1.0",
        "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.1.0",
        "react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
        "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
        "react-dropzone": "^3.4.0",
        "react-functional": "^1.2.0",
        "react-grid-layout": "^0.13.0",
        "react-modal": "^1.4.0",
        "react-player": "^0.12.0",
        "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
        "react-router": "^3.0.0-beta.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
        "react-rte": "^0.5.0",
        "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
        "react-stateless": "^0.2.1",
        "redux": "^3.5.2",
        "redux-crud": "^1.0.0",
        "redux-form": "^5.2.5",
        "redux-saga": "^0.14.2",
        "reselect": "^2.2.1",
        "seamless-immutable": "^5.1.1",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
      }
    }
```

The line I marked "this is false" is where I have most question about. how can I test that the child component InlineEdit will be given props XYZ?

Thank you!

Comment: What test runner/assertion library are you using? I just copy/pasted your code into a project that is using enzyme with mocha & chai and it passes. The only thing I had to change was that chai uses `to.equal` as the syntax instead of `toEqual`. Your test really should pass. Of course, you could always `find(InlineEdit)` and then check its `props()` as an alternative, but what you have should also work.

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for responding! I'm using expect. Is it what you are asking?

Comment: Yes that is your assertion library - what about the test runner (i.e. mocha, jasmine, karma, etc.)? Maybe update the question with that info as well as the code used for your `<InlineEdit />` component. I made a very simple component for that. I wonder if something is happening there also. Maybe try making a fake `<InlineEdit />` that is little more than a `<div></div>` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Also, are you importing the `<InlineEdit />` component into your test script? It will fail if you don't do that.

Comment: It's just a guess, but if InlineEdit defines defaultProps then I'm guessing your assertion will fail.  I've never used .contains but if you assign `InlineEdit.displayName = 'InlineEdit'` then you can use it as a selector: `expect(output.find('InlineEdit').prop('name')).toEqual(props.project.name)`

Comment: Yes, I am using Mocha, I added the whole package.json and the rest of the LineItemRow.spec.js as well as the InlineEdit.js.